# Use HTTP 1.0 in Apache VirtualHost

Tags: http, apache-2.4, cloudflare

I would like to use only HTTP 1.0 on a certain VirtualHost in Apache. The reason for doing so is that I use CloudFlare, and my apps requires the Content-Length header in the HTTP response. However, CloudFlare only forwards the Content-Length header if HTTP 1.0 is used as the protocol (refer to this support ticket: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/requests/527063).

My question here is how do I easily set up a certain VirtualHost in Apache to accomplish this (force the use of HTTP 1.0 as the protocol)? Do I use something like SetEnv in a sites-available config file? Or perhaps, I use the HTTP 1.1 protocol, but send HTTP 1.0 as the protocol in the header?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/apache-the-definitive/0596002033/re249.html here are examples of using the `force-response-1.0` variable with `BrowserMatch`.

```
#
# The following directives modify normal HTTP response behavior.
# The first directive disables keepalive for Netscape 2.x and browsers that
# spoof it. There are known problems with these browser implementations.
# The second directive is for Microsoft Internet Explorer 4.0b2
# which has a broken HTTP/1.1 implementation and does not properly
# support keepalive when it is used on 301 or 302 (redirect) responses.
#
BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

#
# The following directive disables HTTP/1.1 responses to browsers which
# are in violation of the HTTP/1.0 spec by not being able to grok a
# basic 1.1 response.
#
BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0
```

with official docs at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html#special which state

> **force-response-1.0**
>
> This forces an HTTP/1.0 response to clients making an HTTP/1.0 request. It was originally implemented as a result of a problem with AOL's proxies. Some HTTP/1.0 clients may not behave correctly when given an HTTP/1.1 response, and this can be used to interoperate with them.